# Nested loops with a Rust `Sender` and the Rayon's `for_each_with()`

Tags: multithreading, rust, rayon

I have some multithreaded code that involves using a nested loop, where the inner one is run in parallel. "Shared" across each thread is a `Sender` that will return results. Notably `Sender` implements `Send` so there should be no problem cloning it and sending it using Rayon's `for_each_with()`. However, compiling this code:

```rust
use std::sync::mpsc::channel;
use rayon::prelude::*;

fn main(){
    let (sender, receiver) = channel();

    (0..5).for_each(|i|{
        (0..5).into_par_iter().for_each_with(&sender, |sender, j|{
            sender.send(i + j).unwrap();   
        });
    });
}
```

Gives me:

```
8 |         (0..5).into_par_iter().for_each_with(&sender, |sender, j|{
  |                                              ^^^^^^^ `Sender<_>` cannot be shared between threads safely
  |
  = help: the trait `Sync` is not implemented for `Sender<_>`
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Send` for `&Sender<_>`
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=672cca8549c65d2b17e2e8236bbe6261))

Now I was thinking this might be because I'm trying to clone a reference, but if I move the actual `sender` into `for_each_with()` (ie `for_each_with(sender, ...)`), it will be consumed by the first iteration of the outer loop:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `sender`, a captured variable in an `FnMut` closure
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3d27dfdaf41f1cd4bcd54a5648374424)).

How can I implement this pattern in a way that satisfies the Rust compiler?

Comment: just clone https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=93126213bb401a5c204ac916bf8fb516

Comment: style warning, `for_each` is bad and make no sense, use for loop, the world thanks you.

Comment: I disagree, I find `for_each` much more readable as part of a long chain of iterator methods. And anyway I'm using `try_for_each` and `for_each_with` which add extra functionality not suited to a `for` loop.

Comment: It's good that cloning fixes this, but I want to know a) why I need to do so, and b) doesn't that mean I'm cloning `n x m + m` times, n for the inner loop and m for the outer loop? Because `for_each_with` is supposed to clone the `init` argument meaning we have `n x m` clones, but calling clone directly adds another `m` clones. That seems wasteful

Comment: I can't answer a question about sense when code doesn't make sense, yes the clone could be avoid if `for_each_with` return the init item. But it doesn't probably because your first loop doesn't make sense in read world case. I didn't use rayon and I don't like it much. also clone a sender is cheap. "And anyway I'm using try_for_each and for_each_with which add extra functionality not suited to a for loop." my advice was only for `for_each` from std. "why I need to do so" if you send `&sender` you ask to rayon to clone a reference and as compiler say it's not safe to share across thread.

Comment: was thinking about this issue, one solution could be to use `ToOwned` in rayon instead of `Clone`

Comment: It looks like `to_owned()` calls `clone()` behind the scenes.

Comment: no nevermind you miss understand but anyway to_owned would face same problem cause a reference need sync to implement send and sender from std doesn't implement sync.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, Rayon use a threadpool, this mean that rayon require the item to implement `Send` cause it will send it to a thread. rayon doesn't clone for each item but for each thread:

```rust
fn for_each_with<OP, T>(self, init: T, op: OP) where
    OP: Fn(&mut T, Self::Item) + Sync + Send,
    T: Send + Clone,
```

We can see the `OP` take a `&mut T` not a `T`. This mean [`for_each_with()`](https://docs.rs/rayon/1.5.1/rayon/iter/trait.ParallelIterator.html#method.for_each_with) clone for each number of thread used not for the number of item produce.

[Reference need to implement `Sync` to implement `Send`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/marker/trait.Send.html#impl-Send-8). [`Sender` is define to not implement `Sync`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/sync/mpsc/struct.Sender.html#impl-Sync). I don't know the detail of this choice anyway this mean `&Sender` can't be share between thread. I don't think there is solution to remove this constrain.

But if you want you could use [crossbeam-channel](https://crates.io/crates/crossbeam-channel) that implement `Sync`:

```rust
use crossbeam_channel::unbounded; // 0.5.1
use rayon::prelude::*; // 1.5.1

fn main() {
    let (sender, _receiver) = unbounded();

    for i in 0..5 {
        (0..5).into_par_iter().for_each_with(&sender, |sender, j| {
            sender.send(i + j).unwrap();
        });
    }
}
```

would compile fine. Bonus is that crossbeam-channel claim to be faster. That said, cloning is totally fine for the std `Sender`:

```rust
use rayon::prelude::*;
use std::sync::mpsc::channel;

fn main() {
    let (sender, _receiver) = channel();

    for i in 0..5 {
        let sender = sender.clone();
        (0..5).into_par_iter().for_each_with(sender, |sender, j| {
            sender.send(i + j).unwrap();
        });
    }
}
```

That would indeed clone `O(n)` time more but `Sender` from std is mean to be clone a lot. (Actually it's probably just add one clone cause you choice to make a nested loop, the code probably doesn't clone the last one but just give it the last thread and so you just clone one too much as we can [test](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4d8169f7b5d587eb1581098f91978c5a))

Anyway, all your problems come from a strange situation, one should flatten the iteration like:

```rust
use rayon::prelude::*;
use std::sync::mpsc::channel;

fn main() {
    let (sender, _recever) = channel();

    (0..5)
        .into_par_iter()
        .flat_map_iter(|i| (0..5).map(move |j| (i, j)))
        .for_each_with(sender, |sender, (i, j)| {
            sender.send(i + j).unwrap();
        });
}
```

You could also consider not using `Sender` rayon is probably mean to be use with `collect()` and instead of sending the item you could just collect them at the end.

Comment: Lots of great explanations and solutions here, thanks. So if Rayon only clones once per thread, does that mean that the use of `.clone()` will only end up with `n + t` clones, where `n` is the number of iterations in the outer loop, and `t` is the number of threads? Because that's completely tolerable.

Comment: @Migwell no it's `n * t` (probably) cause you do n iteration where rayon clone (t - 1) time but you clone yourself 1 time so `n * (t - 1 + 1)`, since you didn't really use the original sender, you clone one too much. Again AFAIK maybe rayon doesn't do this exactly.

Comment: @Migwell Actually we can test it a little https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=44eb3ffcdee07bd47b08735fee5bb615

Answer (score -2):

`Sender` is made to be cloned, its literally [in the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/fn.channel.html). Each child thread has to have its own sender.

Comment: My problem is slightly more subtle than that. I realise that the sender needs to be cloned and am happy to do this, but `for_each_with` *does the cloning for me*, so any additional cloning that I do is needless.